# I am trying to display Worley Noise, does anyone understand why the output looks like this? Using SFML 2.5.1

Tags: c++, sfml, noise

I am trying to make a Worley noise generator based off of the tutorial by The Coding Train here
https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/coding-in-the-cabana/004-worley-noise.html.

But running the program gives me an output like this: [image: Text]
Rather than [image: Text]

The output of `std::cout << closest << "||" << dist << '\n';` looks like this:

```
1||50
1||51
1||51
1||52
1||53
1||54
1||55
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||34
1||35
1||35
1||35
1||36
1||36
1||36
```

or

```
0||23
0||23
0||23
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||22
0||23
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

// Gets the distance between two points
int pythagor(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
    int xDist = abs(x2 - x);
    int yDist = abs(y2 - y);

    //std::cout << sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) << "|";
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}

// Finds the closest point.
int sort(sf::Vertex points[32], int x, int y)
{
    int start[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        start[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 33; i++)
    {
        int a = start[i-1];
        int b = start[i];
        sf::Vector2f pos = points[i-1].position;
        sf::Vector2f pos2 = points[i].position;

        int dist1 = pythagor(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
        int dist2 = pythagor(x, y, pos2.x, pos2.y);

        if (dist1 > dist2)
        {
            start[i-1] = b;
            start[i] = a;
        }

        //std::cout << dist1 << "|" << dist2 << "|" << start[i-1] << "|" << start[i] << '\n' ;
    }

    return start[0];
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // Variables.
    int pointRes = 32;
    int xRes = 1000, yRes = 1000;

    // Classes.
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(xRes, yRes), "Whorley noise!");

    // Shapes
    sf::Vertex points[pointRes];
    sf::VertexArray points2(sf::Points, xRes*yRes);

    // Random number generator.
    std::mt19937 gen((unsigned) time(NULL)); // Establish Seed.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrX(0, xRes); // Creates A Range Usabele By Gen On The X Axis.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrY(0, yRes); // Creates A Range Usabele By Gen On The X Axis.

    // Generates initial points.
    for (int i = 0; i < pointRes; i++)
    {
        sf::Vector2f pos;
        pos.x = distrX(gen);
        pos.y = distrY(gen);

        points[i].position = sf::Vector2f(pos);

        //std::cout << pos.x << "|" << pos.y << "|" << i << '\n';
    }

    // Generates pixels.
    for (int i = 0; i < xRes-1; i++)
    {   
        for (int o = 0; o < yRes-1; o++)
        {
            sf::Vector2f pPos = sf::Vector2f(i, o);
            points2[((i+1) * yRes) - o].position = pPos;

            int closest = sort(points, i, o);
            int dist = pythagor(i, o, points[closest].position.x, points[closest].position.y);
            points2[(i * o) + o].color = sf::Color(dist, dist, dist);

            //std::cout << closest << "||" << dist << '\n';
        }
    }   
    
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(points2);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Reference Code (Processing)

```
// Worley Noise
// Coding in the Cabana
// The Coding Train / Daniel Shiffman
// https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingInTheCabana/004-worley-noise.html
// https://youtu.be/4066MndcyCk
// p5 port: https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/QsiCWVczZ

PVector[] points = new PVector[100];

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = new PVector(random(width), random(height), random(width));
  }
}

void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

      float[] distances = new float[points.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        PVector v = points[i];
        float z = frameCount % width;
        float d = dist(x, y, z, v.x, v.y, v.z);
        distances[i] = d;
      }
      float[] sorted = sort(distances);
      float r = map(sorted[0], 0, 150, 0, 255);
      float g = map(sorted[1], 0, 50, 255, 0);
      float b = map(sorted[2], 0, 200, 255, 0);
      int index = x + y * width;
      pixels[index] = color(r, g, b);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();

  //noLoop();
  //for (PVector v : points) {
  //  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  //  strokeWeight(8);
  //  point(v.x, v.y);
  //  //v.x += random(-1, 1);
  //  //v.y += random(-1, 1);
  //}
}
```

Comment: At a very quick glance, in `sort()`, `int b = start[i+1];` is out of bound access - should be `int b = start[i-1];` perhaps? - and the `for` loop `for (int i = 1; i < 33; i++)` should have an upper bound of `32`. EDIT: Actually `int a = start[i-1]; int b = start[i];` looks better?

Comment: Are you sure you're using SFML 2.5.4 ?

Comment: I am using SFML 2.5.1

Comment: I implemented the changes you recommended, it seems to have changed the output above from 2 or 0, to 1 or 0.

Comment: It helped if you posted the "good" code that generates the reference image. `int pythagor`  Is working in integers (as opposed to floating point) part of the algorithm?

Comment: I didn't think to use floats, i'll check if that fixes the issue. EDIT: No change when using floats. @dxiv